# Attach existing VPC while creating an ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

When I create an ECS cluster on the AWS UI, I have the option to select a VPC. But how do I select or attach an existing VPC while creating a cluster using Terraform?

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "gtm" {
  name = "gtm"
  setting {
    name  = "containerInsights"
    value = "enabled"
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean VPC and not VPN, because you tagged this with VPC, and VPN makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mark mentioned, it is ECS service level. `network_configuration.subnets` helps to attach subnet. In the Terraform registry page (in Mark's link), there is no explicit sample for network configuration, so I added it below.

**Sample Code:**

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs_service" {
 name            = "my-ecs-service"
 cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.gtm.id
 task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs_task_definition.arn

 network_configuration {
   subnets         = [aws_subnet.subnet.id]
   security_groups = [aws_security_group.security_group.id]
 }
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The VPC is not set at the cluster level, it is set at the ECS [service level](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#network_configuration), by specifying the VPC subnets you want the service to use.